# Determine the error on f(x) knowing R² and best fit for a set of points

Tags: correlation

As a concrete example, I have four points:

```
 x |  y
---+------
 1 | 1854
 2 | 2174
 3 | 2258
 4 | 2953
```

The best linear fit for these four points is `f(x) = 338.1x + 1464.5` with `R² = 0.889467`.

Knowing that, I can predict `f(5) = 3155.0`, but can I use `f` and `R²` to determine an error or standard deviation function `σ(x)` on `f(x)`, e.g. `f(5) = 3155.0 ± σ(5)`? I guess the farther out you go from the known data, the larger `σ(x)` will be.

Comment: You either give a pointwise error which is the pointwise difference from prediction or you give an "educated" overall estimate of the error (standard error)